# Performance tuning in teradata for view

Tags: sql, teradata

I have created a view as below :

```
REPLACE    VIEW EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP AS
LOCKING    ROW FOR ACCESS   (
  SELECT 'P2' AS REGION_CD , a.* FROM EDB_MAN_WORK.EMP_IND a
  UNION 
  SELECT 'Z2' AS REGION_CD , b.* FROM EDB_MAN_WORK.EMP_US b
  UNION 
  SELECT 'I2' AS REGION_CD , c.* FROM EDB_MAN_WORK.EMP_UK c
);
```

I am running below query on the view but this is taking time.

```
SELECT EMP_IND.CUST_NO,EMP_US.REGION_CD,EMP_UK.CUST_TYPE
FROM EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_IND,
     EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_US,
     EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_UK
WHERE EMP_UK.CNTL_ENT_no = EMP_US.CNTL_ENT_no
AND EMP_US.CUST_no = EMP_IND.CUST_no
AND EMP_UK.REGION_CD = EMP_US.REGION_CD
AND EMP_US.REGION_CD = EMP_IND.REGION_CD
GROUP BY  CUST_NO,REGION_CD,CUST_TYPE
```

I want to tune this query but we cant create SI on the view.
Please help me in optimizing this query.

Comment: You're not accessing the view in your query. And of course you should change UNION to UNION ALL to avoid the DISTINCT overhead

Comment: change UNION in UNION ALL. You have put P2, Z2, I2 so your query will return different rows by 3 data sets. Add index on REGION_CD field

Comment: Thanks dnoeth and Joe.

Comment: REGION_CD is not in the any tables and we are hardcoding it into view so how i can create index on REGION_CD filed.

Comment: You can't create an index on that column in Teradata. And if this was allowed the optimizer will never use it as it's not selective ebnough. And i still don't get what you're doing: Your view is called EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP but in your query you access EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_IND, EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_US and EDB_MAN_VWS.EMP_UK. And EMP_UK.REGION_CD = EMP_US.REGION_CD should never evaluate to true as UK = 'I2' and US = 'Z2'?

Comment: @dnoeth I cant put exact SQL here so tried to put simplified version by using dummy tables.

Comment: Without exact info I can't suggest nothing else but the UNION ALL.